# Using Winforms control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application, through the library System.Windows.Form can create a winform window, which can add controls winform.
To compile in visual studio it works fine but when IIS publish this window is not displayed.
Is there any way to achieve the IIS deploy the winform? or some way to publish this application?
Any ideas?

Sorry for my bad English
Thanks

Comment: What control is it you're trying to use on your web page, out of interest?

Comment: Even if you succeeded in doing what you are trying to  do (I recall reading somewhere it's possible if you jump through enough hoops) , the application will not work on any machines that don't have .NET.

Comment: This is possible. but you must configure the IIS and the server. In this case it succeeds and works. I have not had problems with any user.
This link guide me http://www.locualo.net/programacion/ejecutar-programas-traves-servicio-web/00000071.aspx

thanks for your answers